# JavaScript Renaming Form Image Input Name

Tags: javascript, html, dom, forms

I am developing this for use in Internet Explorer 8 (because at work we have to use it). I have a page that has a table withing a form. The table has a button to "clone" rows, "*AddScheduleRow()*". That part works good. Each row has a button to delete that row "*DeleteRow(r)*". That part works well too. I also have a script to rename/renumber each row, "*RenumberRows()*". It almost works good. I can rename the text fields (for example what was previously StartDate3 now becomes StartDate2). However, in each row is an input that is type="image" and it is named like you should with any input. The name of it is "StartDateCal". The problem is that during the renaming process, when it hits the image input (*TheForm.StartDateCal[i].name = "StartDateCal" + TempCounter;*), I get a JavaScript error "'TheForm.StartDateCal' is null or not an object". I cannot figure this one out and it's standing in the way of moving on.

What can I do to try to rename an < input type = image /> ?

Below is the necessary code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="UpdateSchedule" method="post" action="DoSchedule.asp">
            <input type="hidden" name="NumRows" value="0">
            <input type="hidden" name="RowsAdded" value="0">
            <table id="ClassScheduleTable">
                <tr id="ScheduleRow" style="display:none;">
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="RowNum" value="0" size="1" onclick="alert(this.name)">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Start Date</b> <input type="text" name="StartDate" value="" onclick="alert(this.name);" size="8">&nbsp;
                        <input type="image" name="StartDateCal" src="http://www.CumminsNorthwest.com/ATT/Img/Calendar3.png" style="border-style:none;" onClick="alert('name = ' + this.name);return false;">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" value="Del." name="DelRow" class="subbuttonb" onclick="DeleteRow(this);">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:right">
                    <input type="button" value="Add Class Date" class="SubButton" onclick="AddScheduleRow();">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>    
<script language="JavaScript">
```

**JS**

```
    var TheForm = document.forms.UpdateSchedule;
    var NumRows =0;
    var RowsAdded =0;
    function AddScheduleRow(){
        NumRows++;
        TheForm.NumRows.value = NumRows;
        RowsAdded++;
        TheForm.RowsAdded.value = RowsAdded;

        var TableRowId = "ScheduleRow";
        var RowToClone = document.getElementById(TableRowId);
        var NewTableRow = RowToClone.cloneNode(true);

        NewTableRow.id = TableRowId + NumRows ;
        NewTableRow.style.display = "table-row";

        var NewField = NewTableRow.children;

        for (var i=0;i<NewField.length;i++){
            var TheInputFields = NewField[i].children;
            for (var x=0;x<TheInputFields.length;x++){
                var InputName = TheInputFields[x].name;
                if (InputName){
                    TheInputFields[x].name = InputName + NumRows;
                    //alert(TheInputFields[x].name);
                }
                var InputId = TheInputFields[x].id;
                if (InputId){
                    TheInputFields[x].id = InputId + NumRows;
                //alert(TheInputFields[x].id);
                }
            }
        }

        var insertHere = document.getElementById(TableRowId);
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(NewTableRow,insertHere);
        RenumberRows();
    }

    AddScheduleRow();

    function DeleteRow(r){
        var i=r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
        document.getElementById("ClassScheduleTable").deleteRow(i);
        NumRows--;
        TheForm.NumRows.value = NumRows;
        RenumberRows();
    }

    function RenumberRows(){
        var TempCounter = 0;
        for (var i=0;i<=RowsAdded;i++){
            if (TheForm.RowNum[i]){
                TempCounter++;
                TheForm.RowNum[i].name = "RowNum" + TempCounter;
                TheForm.RowNum[i].value = TempCounter;
                TheForm.StartDate[i].name = "StartDate" + TempCounter;
                TheForm.StartDateCal[i].name = "StartDateCal" + TempCounter;
            }
        }
    }


</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

might be to do with your DTD,

try HTML4 Strict:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
document.getElementsByName('StartDateCal')[i].name = "StartDateCal" + TempCounter;
```

instead of

```
TheForm.StartDateCal[i].name = "StartDateCal" + TempCounter;
```

Comment: That works. Not sure why ot works that way instead of treating it like a normal form element, but it works.

Comment: Nice to know :). But you may better use the solution to set your doctype like achusonline wrote it. You just have to insert that line to the top of your document. Also before the <html>-tag. i tried that solution and it also works. Its just seem to be the cleaner solution.